# Was Brody drugged to make him talk?

Tags: plot-explanation, homeland

In S2 E5, Brody, handcuffed, is being questioned by Carrie.

Carrie offers him some water, and Brody accepts.

[image]

Then, after a lengthy verbal exchange,

> Brody finally talks, and tells the truth about his involvement in terrorism.

After that he seems very tired and falls asleep, on the ground.

Did the water contain some drug to get Brody to talk?

Comment: Seemed to me more like skilful interrogation more than " a lengthy verbal exchange". why would you believe their were drugs involved?

Comment: @Paulie_D, I don't remember all of the fine details, but Brody became a heroine addict at some point and drugs are recurring theme throughout the series.

Comment: @DarthLocke it wouldn't make any sense to have drugs used in this scene and never mentioned again...

Comment: They can of insisted on the water (Carrie's offer, close-up on Brody drinking...), so a drug use could be "suggested". Brody endures a (certainly) skillful interrogation but, nevertheless, starts talking quite easily after, and ended up sleeping on the flour (maybe because he felt liberated after the confession, but, we don't know). All of that suggests he might have been drugged, while it's never mentioned (as far as I can remember),

Comment: @Luciano it might, because the show is nuanced enough that it doesn't address every under-handed thing or given action any given character does. Hence my own question about the series finale I just posted, but as mentioned, it has been a while since I watched the earlier seasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### We'll never know.

It's never mentioned in the later episodes.

It's possible, as you state in your question and some commenters suggest, but at the same time:

- it's a lengthy interrogation process
- they make him watch his own confession then leave him there for a while
- Quinn stuck a knife through his hand!

The whole process is designed to wear a person out and lower their psychologic defense so they will talk more easily. It would be understandable if he would just be extremely tired after all this.

Comment: We'll never know... unless the question is raised to some of the staff or heard in a special features comment...

Comment: @e2-e4 yes. So far it hasn't been mentioned anywhere, and it's been a while already that episode aired  - the series has ended on season 8. Perhaps on some DVD release with commentary.